# How to run 'rake db:drop' in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a rails app running on the Elastic Beanstalk service.

When I deploy my app, some pages didn't work. I think the problem is that after I delete a model and create a new model with the same name but different schema, the database didn't reset.

On local, I can run `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` to reset the database. However, how to reset the database on EB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to run it manually, you can simply `eb ssh` your environment and issue the `rake` commands. Alternatively if you don't need that db, simply recreate the environment from the beanstalk web console, which will recreate the db.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to run the `rake` commands on ssh. It says `No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)`, I cannot find the app directory.

Comment: check out `/var/app/current`. make sure you're root (`sudo su -`)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to delete also `structure.rb` file manual from your rails application and let it create again by using `rake db:migrate`